# Implement JPA Repository with filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I want to implement search implementation with filter limitation:

```
@GetMapping("find")
    public Page<MerchantUserDTO> getAllBySpecification(
            @And({
                @Spec(path = "name", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "login", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "email", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
        }) Specification<Users> specification,
            @SortDefault(sort = "login", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable
    ) {        
        return merchantUserService.getAllBySpecification(specification, pageable)
                .map(g -> MerchantUserDTO.builder()                   
                        .id(g.getId())
                        .login(g.getLogin())                        
                        .build()
                );
    }

@Override
    public Page<Users> getAllBySpecification(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable) {
        return dao.findAllByTypeIn(specification, pageable, "MerchantUser");
    }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MerchantUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Users> {

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Pageable page, String... types);

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable, String... types);
}
```

But I get exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query.
```

When I use `dao.findAll(specification, pageable);` and `Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Pageable page, String... types);` it's working fine. Is there some other way to implement limitation for `In ...` clause using the above code?

Comment: Based on my suggestion, Instead of stick spring default methods.
Write your own HQL query.

Example:

 @Query(" select user from User where user.type IN :types and user.specification like %:specification%  ")

List<Users> findAllByTypeIn(String specification, String... types ,  Pageable pageable);

Comment: Not sure why did you introduced `types` parameter as it can be part of the Specification. Use `specification.and(path.in(types))`. Where path is your attribute.

Comment: I updated the post. @t4dohx based on the post what should be used for `path`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov - You don't use static metamodels to build Specifications?

Comment: I use this framework https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver